# Edit data of a WCF Data Service through LINQ

Tags: wcf, linq, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I've created a small WCF Data service, I can Add/retrieve data without any problem.

I've a set on this collection "Household", with all rights:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("HouseHold", EntitySetRights.All);
```

The problem is that I just can't edit:

```
HouseHold houseHold = entities.HouseHold.Where(h => h.IDHouseHold == varContainingAnExistingId).FirstOrDefault();
houseHold.LastName = "LastName" + DateTime.Now;
entities.SaveChanges();
```

I don't have any exception, my data is just not updated in the database.

I'm missing something? I should do something more to save my changes?

(My breakpoint stops on the entities.SaveChanges(), so I'm perfectly sure that it runs)

Thank you very much

Edit, I just saw that the ApplyingChanges of my DataServiceContext is set to false, but it's not a property I can edit, is there a link with my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution by exploring context's methods:

There is no change tracking with wcf data service, you then have to specify that the object has changed. This problem happens only when modifying because when adding/deleting we have to call specials methods which put changes flags automatically.

So with my example, the following code is working:

```
HouseHold houseHold = entities.HouseHold.Where(h => h.IDHouseHold == varContainingAnExistingId).FirstOrDefault();
houseHold.LastName = "LastName" + DateTime.Now;
entities.UpdateObject(houseHold);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

The **UpdateObject** is the important change.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to enable DataServiceConfiguration.UseVerboseErrors?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.useverboseerrors.aspx